# How to change the position of the button to the place we want?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a web site (I'm a beginer in Vuetify ) , and I want to create a button at the extremity of the page(last row even in the center  ,last column) , but this buttun still in the begin of the page , Here is my code  :

```
<template>
<div>
<v-toolbar
  dark
  prominent
  src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg"
>

<v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
<v-toolbar-title>Workers</v-toolbar-title>


</v-toolbar>

<v-row align="center">
 <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
 <v-btn x-large color="pink" >START</v-btn>
 </v-col> 
</v-row>


<v-navigation-drawer app 
v-model="drawer"
.
.
.
</v-navigation-drawer>
</div>
</template>
```

PS: the collor of the button also doesn't change

Thank you !

Comment: Could you explain more about the structure of this code and how you want to position the button? Note that the color changed normally when I tried it.

Comment: Very general Q + without full code example. In your case maybe add a screenshot of the result you want. Use any CSS styles you want to position the button element (position: fixed; for example).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick.

```
<v-row class="align-center">
 <v-col cols="12" sm="6" class="text-right">
 <v-btn x-large color="pink" >START</v-btn>
 </v-col> 
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `v-row` you can manipulate horizontal alignment using `justify` and vertical alignment using `align` like the [official document](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#playground) points out.

For your case to align the button at the end:

```
<v-row justify="end">
  <v-btn>Button</v-btn>
</v-row>
```

Comment: Thanks but why when I put  <v-btn x-large color="pink" >START</v-btn> it doesn't change the color to pink?

Comment: Make sure you wrap everything in `v-app`